# How to specifically position button on Jumbotron?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Can't seem to figure out how to place button specifically with CSS in a jumbotron. I used a few classes like text-left or pull-left, but they just didn't give me the desired look. I'd imagine it's some simple CSS, but I can't seem to get it. I would like to be able to place it specifically based on pixels.

html:

```
<div class="six">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="jumbotron">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-default">→</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: By default it will be aligned to left. What is the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

It would be very hard to tell you what you should do since there is a million ways to place it, we dont know where you want it placed?

Possible solutions could be using creating a container class in jumbotron with CSS property `position: relative`, and then make a custom button class that gets:

```
position: absolute;
top: 100px; (or any other number)
left: 100px;
right 100px;
bottom: 100px;
```

if you just want to center the buttom you can use the default TWBS class text-center. if its a question about moving it just a bit from the left or right add `margin-right / margin-left` to the button.

If you want a more precise solution please proivde a jsfiddle or a image

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" style="margin-bottom: 0; background-color: orange; " >
            <div class="container-lg" >
              <h1 class="display-4 text-white"  >Free Access &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;Start Learning </h1>
              <p class="lead text-white">
                No account required!<br>Just Learn from Scratch absolutely free!
                <a href="index1.html"target="blank" class="btn btn-primary" style="position: relative;margin-left: 850px; margin-top: -90px; ">Start Learning</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
```